# separate verdict template: teplate<... sep ...>

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to separate a verdict template, I'm using `clang++4.0`, on a Ubuntu, I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/array>

using std::array;

struct Dummy {
};

template<int _I, int ... _rest>
constexpr bool test(int _test) {
if constexpr (sizeof...(_rest) == 0) {
    return (_test % _I);
} else {
    return (_test % _I && test<_rest...>(_test));
}
}

template< int ... _I>
constexpr array<int, sizeof...(_I)> make_array() {
return { {_I...}};
}

template<int ... _primes, typename _d, int _test, int ... _todo>
constexpr auto make_prime_array_helper() {
if constexpr (test<_primes...>(_test)) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(_todo) == 0) {
        return make_array<_primes..., _test>();
    } else {
        return make_prime_array_helper<_primes..., _test, _d, _todo...>();
    }
} else {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(_todo) == 0) {
        return make_array<_primes...>();
    } else {
        return make_prime_array_helper<_primes..., _d, _todo...>();
    }
}
}

template<int _I0, int _I1,int _I2,int _I3, int ... _todo> // 0, 1, 2, 3 ....
constexpr auto make_prime_array() {
return make_prime_array_helper<_I2, _I3 , Dummy, _todo...>();
}

int main() {
constexpr auto a = make_prime_array<0, 1, 2, 3, 5>();
std::cout << a[1] << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

but it does not work, I get an error:

```
../src/primearray.cpp:44:9: error: no matching function for call to 'make_prime_array_helper'
        return make_prime_array_helper<_I2, _I3 , Dummy, _todo...>();
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/primearray.cpp:49:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'make_prime_array<0, 1, 2, 3, 5>' requested here
        constexpr auto a = make_prime_array<0, 1, 2, 3, 5>();
                           ^
../src/primearray.cpp:25:16: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter '_primes'
```

I've tried to change `typename _d` to something else like `bool _d` than I get this error:

```
../src/primearray.cpp:24:16: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_d'
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by deducing one of the template parameter packs via function parameter. E.g. the following small modification of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/array>

using std::array;

template<int... _primes> 
struct PrimeSeq {
};

template<int _I, int... _rest>
constexpr bool test(int _test) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(_rest) == 0) {
        return (_test % _I);
    } else {
        return (_test % _I && test<_rest...>(_test));
    }
}

template< int ... _I>
constexpr array<int, sizeof...(_I)> make_array() {
    return { {_I...}};
}

template<int _test, int... _todo, int... _primes>
constexpr auto make_prime_array_helper(PrimeSeq<_primes...>) {
    if constexpr (test<_primes...>(_test)) {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(_todo) == 0) {
            return make_array<_primes..., _test>();
        } else {
            return make_prime_array_helper<_todo...>(PrimeSeq<_primes..., _test>{});
        }
    } else {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(_todo) == 0) {
            return make_array<_primes...>();
        } else {
            return make_prime_array_helper<_todo...>(PrimeSeq<_primes...>{});
        }
    }
}

template<int _I0, int _I1,int _I2,int _I3, int... _todo> // 0, 1, 2, 3 ....
constexpr auto make_prime_array() {
    return make_prime_array_helper<_todo...>(PrimeSeq<_I2, _I3>{});
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto a = make_prime_array<0, 1, 2, 3, 5>();
    std::cout << a[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

will do the job. It works fine when compiled via `clang++-4.0 -std=c++1z`